# Script to append range of data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will copy and send a range of data to another sheet. I want to add another part to the script, that will do the same function but append the data to a new row.

```
  function saveToRecords() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var source = ss.getRange('Report!L1:AC1');
    source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Records!A3:R3'), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
```

I have this script attached to a button in Google Sheets. The data is sent form `Report!` to `Records!`. The `Records!` sheet will save this data. So each time I click the button I would like the data to be sent to a new row.

I know there is an easy way to do this! I have been stumped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, there is. You can use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

So your code would look like this:

```
function appendToRecords() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Records")
  var reportData = reportSheet.getRange("L1:AC1")
                              .getValues();
  var lastRow = recordsSheet.getLastRow();
  //copy data
  recordsSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 12, 1, 18)
              .setValues(reportData);

}
```

Comment: What does the `12, 1, 18` mean/do in the 2nd to last line?
Edit, I believe it's this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)