# Google App Script to append range of data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will copy and send a range of data to another sheet. I want to add another part to the script, that will perform the same function but append the data to the next blank row.

```
function saveToRecords() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var archive = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var source = ss.getRange('Work!A10:R');
    var lastRow = archive.getLastRow();
    source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Archive!A1:R1'), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

I've been following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194190/script-to-append-range-of-data-in-google-sheets) for guidance, but when I attempt to implement the solution, I keep receiving a mismatched range error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with something like this

```
function saveToRecords() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Work'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A10:R').activate();
  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Work");
  var target_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = source_range.getValues();
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
}
```

This adds my A10:R range and pastes values into the first available row in my Archive sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveToRecords() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archive = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var work = ss.getSheetByName('Work');
  var source = work.getRange(10,1,work.getLastRow()-9,18);
  source.copyTo(archive.getRange(archive.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, receiving weird result now

Comment: Also, how does your var source line work? I want to copy over all rows from A10:R that are not blank, but some columns are blank within these rows. When implementing your solution exactly, I would receive and out of range error.

Comment: In your code source is an array of values `var source = ss.getRange('Work!A10:R').getValues()` in my code source is a range `var source = work.getRange(10,1,work.getLastRow()-9,18);`  Also I find that getting values with A1 Notations like `A10:R` result in a large amount of trailing  nulls from the bottom of your data to maxrows so I never use that sort of notation.  If I need to know the last row then I use Sheet.getLastRow() function.

Comment: You really need to start using the debugger and looking at the information about yourr data the debugger is providing.