# How can I possibly get the last row from a range of a sheet using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recently started a project that would automatically update datas of a stock card using google sheet and apps script and I wanted to know how can I get the last row from a range and write datas from it. For example,

[image]

this is the I wanted to update, how can I get the last row from range A14:G53 and automatically paste data from another sheet (database) using apps script.

[image]

I have tried coding and this is what I've got so far

```
function updateStocks(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("database"); //sheet for my datas
  var range = sh.getRange("data") //range from "database sheet"
  var rData = range.getValues();
  rData.forEach((row, i) => {
  //sheetname from "database sheet"
  var sheetname = rData[i][3]; 
  var date = rData[i][9]; //date from "database sheet"
  var iQty = rData[i][4]; //issue qty from "database sheet"
  var iOffice = rData[i][10]; //issue office from "database sheet"
  var bQty = rData[i][13]; //balance qty from "database sheet"

  var data = {date,iQty,iOffice,bQty};
  //Paste values of each row to their respective sheet
  ss.getSheetByName(sheetname).appendRow(data);
  })
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. In your showing script, what is `data` of `var range = sh.getRange("data")`? 2. In your showing script, you are using `var sh = ss.getSheetByName("database");`. But, in your showing sample Spreadsheet and your question, it seems that you don't explain about the sheet `database`. Can I ask you about the detaled relation between your showing script and your showing sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: "data" is not a range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to append range of data in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194190/script-to-append-range-of-data-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I've edited my post a bit. In database sheet, I have a range called "data" where every item has respective sheets. Now from this, I need to update each item sheet from the list in database sheet. I need to get the values from columns J, F, K, and N and paste it to their respective sheet within the range of A14:G53, because I also have some datas written at the last row of each sheet.

Comment: Can you provide us with a copy of the spreadsheet as the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Also, I noticed that the number of columns between the two sheets are different. Can you specify which data from the `database` corresponds to the columns in the `stock card`?

Comment: @PatrickdC From database, I need datas from column J, F, K and N to be transferred. Column J (date) to Date, Column E (request_qty) to Issue Quantity, Column K (issue_office) to Issue Office and Column N (remeaining_qty) to Balance Quantity

Comment: here is a copy of my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oB3pgLbq-GEVyXuRN4oRaJOuG7yXBxrnRS0kiyAzSNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Methodology

Based from the details that you have presented in your post and responses, you should be able to tackle the issues with the following:

1. Use the `getLastRow()` and `getLastColumn()` to determine the limit of the data in the `Database` tab.
2. Use the `map()` to only extract the required data from the `Database` tab. In the script, I have already rearranged the data so that it may be placed in the `Arrow_Stickers` tab in the correct order.
3. In transferring the data to the `Arrow_Stickers` tab, I just reused the `getLastRow()` value in the `getRange()` function and then used `setValues()` directly making sure that both the source and destination arrays have the same array size.

### The Script

You may use the following script as the basis for your own script.

```
function transferData() {
  var ssDb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Database');
  var ssAs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Arrow_Stickers');
  var lr = ssDb.getLastRow();
  var lc = ssDb.getLastColumn();
  var data = ssDb.getRange(4,1,lr-3,lc).getDisplayValues();
  var fData = data.map(data => {
    return [data[9], '', '', data[4], data[10], data[13]];
  })
  ssAs.getRange(14,1,lr-3,6).setValues(fData);
}
```

Please take note that this script is based only from the sample sheets that you have provided (`Database` and `Arrow_Stickers`). I advise you to modify the script accordingly.

### Output

The output of the script should look like this:

[image: Output]

### References

1. [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
2. [Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Answer (score 2):

To get the last row in a google sheet Spreadsheet is pretty straight forward, you could use app script or just put this in a cell = `=Max(filter(row(A:A),A:A<>""))`

A script can easily get it for the whole sheet.

```
function testLastRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
}
```

From there, it's hard to tell if your array is setup correctly, but I would do something like this....

```
  var data = [[date,iQty,iOffice,bQty]]; //this might not be right... but get values.
  var zSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var lastRow = zSheet.getLastRow();
  zSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data .length,data [0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: Hi Sir, is it possible to only get the last row of  the range A14:G53 and not the whole sheet? because I also have datas/cell values at the end of each sheet

Comment: @Sky Yes it is, the answer is essentially in my first sentence with just a nominal modification. However, that was not your original question and you have received three pretty decent answers to your less than impressive question and have not `accepted` any. Stack Overflow is not a free help service. Perhaps `accept` an answer and go back and work on it on your own and if you really can't figure it out, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=INDEX('Arrow_Stickers'!A:A,MATCH(143^143,'Arrow_Stickers'!A:A))

This will return the last used cell in column A.  The 143^143 is just creating a super large number that will always be bigger than what you use in column A.

This answer comes from here:
https://spreadsheetpoint.com/get-last-value-in-column-google-sheets/

To use it within your App Script you may have to put the formula in a cell within your Sheet, then reference that cell in the App Script.